# The font can't be find the font under font-family after copy the link from google font to the <head> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5.1

The font can't be find under font-family while styling after copy the link from google font to the  tag. I have try using the script format it still not working.

Comment: can you improve your question by sharing your code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the font in the CSS file

```
* {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-sefif
}
```

Comment: h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 3rem;  line-height: 1.5;  font-weight: 900;}

Comment: If you put your code into your question instead of a comment it would help us help you. Are you certain you are loading the font at that weight for example? We can't tell from what you have shown us so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Using the asterisk selector to define a font is not recommended. You might also want to use other fonts like an icon font. A better solution would be to define the font family on the `body` element, it will be inherited.